# Java Regex Matcher matches . (dot) even if it is not in Pattern

Tags: java, android

I want to parse semicolon separated string, that has or has not semicolon at the end

I have Regex Pattern `(\s*\w+)(\s*;)*` which I interpret as to match:

0..n spaces followed by 1..n characters followed by 0..n spaces that end with semicolon.

My problem is that I get "wrong match" if there is a '.' in input string
Example:

```
0000.274283;518600.00-F10W;
```

Instead of expected '0000.274283;' I get '0000'.

What am I missing?

Comment: \w does not match the dot character. It matches alphanumeric characters and the underscore (_).

Comment: You did see the last `*` behind the second capture group? The first capture group matches `0000` and the second capture group is matched 0 times.

Answer (score 0):

\w matches any word character. So you are matching 0-n spaces followed by 1 or more letter, number, or underscore. Since '.' is not included, your regex will not match strings with a '.' in it, hence why you only get 0000 instead of 0000.274283

Comment: I am banging my head against the wall here trying to write regex to parse this string: "0000.274283;518600.00-F10W;0274283;04.09.2014;03.09.2017;0000274118;000110;13477" I know I could use split, but i need it to be regex (other requirements). Any suggestions ?

Comment: If some numbers you need to match can have a '.' in it you could use '?' to make matching against '.' optional.
For example if I want to match against numbers that could be 8 digits (i.e. 1234.1234 or 12341234) I could match \d{4}\.?\d{4}

Answer (score 0):

`[^;]+` matches everything except a semicolon, so maybe you could use this one to split your given string by semicolon.